# Do occupied minecarts float?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, depending on the answer to my question about village distance, I am coming up with some ideas about "Villager Storage Systems". One question though is: Do minecarts float?

This comes from the plan to float villagers up in a water stream. However I need to use minecarts to get my storage system working properly. So if I put a Villager in a minecart, will they float in water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecarts do not float with passengers inside of them, as seen in the picture below.

I tested it in version 1.11.2.

[image]